# What's a natural way to say "I am getting familiar with something"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-choice, alternatives

I am looking for a simple and natural way to express the process of getting familiar with something.

Some options I've been considering include

> I am acquainting myself with something.
>
> I am getting familiar with something.
>
> I am getting acquainted with something.
>
> I am making myself familiar with something.

All the sentences are in Present Progressive because it seems to me like a reasonable way to express a continuing action. Also, I am wondering if Present Simple can be used as well.

Thank you.

---

Someone voted to close it as primarily opinion-based. Sorry, I didn't get it. I am not asking the "best" way to say it. I would like you to validate my sentences and suggest yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is "I'm getting used to it."

Comment: Hi Becnal, welcome to ELL. Please take a look at the Help pages - https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer it's best to try and back up your answers with sources and references as well as explaining the reasons behind your answer

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way to use "familiar" would be:

> I am familiarising myself with it.

"Acquainted" *can* be used for *things*, but "getting acquainted" is more commonly used to describe *people* mutually getting to know one another. I would therefore use:

> I am acquainting myself with it.

As this idiomatically shows it is you putting the effort in to get to know something.